# Error 1265: Data truncated for column, when trying to convert a column from vatrchar to float

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, temp-tables, alter-table

I have a table 'runner_orders' like below:
[image]

I made a temporary table 'runner_orders_clean' and cleaned the data as such:
[image]

I then tried to change the datatype of a few columns like distance, duration. The code is as below:

```
ALTER TABLE runner_orders_clean
MODIFY COLUMN distance FLOAT;
```

I get the following error:
[image]

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong. Is this because of temporary tables, or is my code wrong or is this not possible? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.I'm doing this on MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Note that the complaint appears to be with the rows that appear to be empty strings (the error references row 6) ... maybe convert those to 0 instead?

Comment: First update those blank values in distance field to '0.00', and then convert the column from vatrchar to float.

Comment: Those rows had value null, so I replaced them with blank ' '. If I convert it into 0, it won't work for pickup_time column, right?

Comment: The data is really truncated. The tail containing the unit of measurement must be cut off during the conversion. I.e. the information will be partially lost - and strict mode prevents this data loss. Either set non-strict SQL Mode for ALTER TABLE statement or execute UPDATE before the datatype convertion and cut off the unit tail. PS. I'd recommend to use DECIMAL datatype instead of FLOAT. And maybe even INT for duration column.